# ViewState not working ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I stumbled a very odd problem. My viewState is not working in my ASP.NET application. What I mean is that the application doesn't recognize when the page is postback and all of the viewState variable are losing their values. I tried a lot of solution from other similar posts but none of them worked.

> The things I have tried:
>   1. I set EnableViewState to true everywhere;
>   2. In the form tag set action="Default.aspx";
>   3. Resetting my web.config;
>   4. In the default.aspx in Page_Load set this.Page.Master.EnableViewState = true;
>   5. Adding sessiong state to web.config;

And quite much more but these are the main things. I don't know where the error  is so I can give you the whole code: [source](https://github.com/simooo93/SnowyStudio-website/tree/master/SnowyStudio)

Answer (score 0):

in the pageload are you checking  if (!IsPostBack) and then setting the viewstate?